# Web audio API - LFO with 'triangle' shape connected to biquadFilter clicks

Tags: web-audio-api

I have an LFO connected to a biquadFilter.

When the LFO gain is greater than the current biquadFilter.frequency.value, it results in notice-able clicking of audio.

Is there a way prevent this clicking ?

The biquadFilter has an envelope on it, so the frequency sweeps up and down after a note on the keyboard is pressed.

This is what I think is happening :

[image: LFO cutting through envelope value.]

This is what I'd like to happen : 
[image: LFO respecting the filter.]

Here is a minimal example : 
http://codepen.io/js-bs/pen/bgyZPx

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var masterGain = audioContext.createGain()
masterGain.connect(audioContext.destination)
masterGain.gain.value = .3;

// Filter
var filter = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
filter.type = 'lowpass'
filter.frequency.value = 0;
filter.connect(masterGain);

// Oscillator
var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
osc.frequency.value = 440;
osc.type = 'square';
osc.start();
osc.connect(filter);

// LFO
var lfo = this.audioContext.createOscillator();
var lfoGain = this.audioContext.createGain();
lfo.type = 'triangle';
lfo.start();
lfo.connect(lfoGain);
lfo.frequency.value = 5;
lfoGain.gain.value = 10000;
lfoGain.connect(filter.frequency);

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.id==='lfo' && e.target.checked){
    lfo.connect(lfoGain);
  } else if (e.target.id==='lfo') {
    lfo.disconnect();
  }
})

document.addEventListener('mousedown', filterEnvelopeOn);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', filterEnvelopeOff);

function filterEnvelopeOn () {
  let now = audioContext.currentTime;
  let frequency = filter.frequency;
  let attack = 0.5;
  let decay = 0.4;
  let sustain = 200;

  let freq = 10000;
  frequency.cancelScheduledValues(0)
  frequency.setValueAtTime(60, now)
  frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(freq, now + attack)
  frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(sustain, now + attack + decay)
}

 function filterEnvelopeOff () {
   filter.frequency.cancelScheduledValues(0);
   let now = audioContext.currentTime;
   let frequency = filter.frequency;
   let release = 0.1;
   frequency.cancelScheduledValues(0);
   frequency.setValueAtTime(frequency.value, now);
   frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, now + release);
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a smaller example? I don't feel like reading and understanding how to use all of the libraries you're using.

Comment: Yes, I can create a minimal reproduction.   I'm not using any web audio libraries, just the standard library when it comes to audio.   The libraries I'm using are just for the UI.

Comment: That would be fantastic.  Thanks!

Comment: @RaymondToy I updated my question with a minimal reproduction and some images to better explain what's happening.   Essentially, I'd like the LFO to respect the filter envelope's current value.   I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I change my codepen example code from :
>
> lfoGain.connect(filter.frequency);
>
> to :
>
> lfoGain.connect(filter.detune);
>
> The audible clicking is gone, and the synth sounds as I intend it to.
>
> If anyone can explain why this works that would be helpful and I'll mark your answer as accepted.

When you have AudioNodes connected to an AudioParam, that AudioParam takes its value as all of the outputs from the AudioNodes and its own value added together. In your case, the values output by your lfoGain range from -10000 to +10000, because the output of the oscillator ranges from -1 to 1, and those values are then multiplied by your lfoGain.gain value.

When you have your lfoGain connected to the frequency, you're telling the frequency to oscillate between 0Hz and +20000Hz (10000 ± 10000) immediately after the attack of your envelope, between -9800Hz and +10200Hz (200 ± 10000) at your sustain, and between -10000Hz and +10000Hz ( 0 ± 10000 ) after the release of your envelope.

When you instead have your lfoGain connected to the detune, the computed frequency will oscillate proportionally to the frequency value you set with the envelope.

> computedFrequency(t) = frequency(t) * pow(2, detune(t) / 1200)

You're now telling the detune value to oscillate between -10000cents and +10000cents (0 ± 10000 ), and this oscillation, rather than adding to the frequency, multiplies it by a value that's approximately between 1/323 and 323.

Immediately after the envelope's attack, the minimum computed frequency in the oscillation is approximately 31Hz, at the sustain, the minimum is approximately 0.62Hz, and after the release of your envelope, the computed frequency range is between 0 and 0 (0/323, 0*323).

This is at least what it's being told to do, actual implementation may be different.

Comment: based on your answer , is it possible to connect the LFO to the "frequency" AudioParam and not have audible clicking ?    If the filter is at a known value that doesn't change over time -- then it seems possible to connect the  LFO to the "frequency" AudioParam without audible clicking.   However, since the filter sweeps it values over time, the LFO would need to adjust its gain accordingly-- and this is not really possible.

Comment: You could modify the value of lfoGain.gain using the same envelope that changes the filter's frequency. I made a quick edit to your pen to show the result of this:

http://codepen.io/ivthefourth/pen/vxGJaV

You could also try using a custom PeriodicWave to make an offset triangle waveform that has a range from 0 to 1 instead of -1 to 1. In this case, the result would be similar to your initial situation at the lower frequency values, but there would be no negative values, potentially eliminating the clicking. The lack of negative values would make the top of your envelope sound different.

Comment: cool thanks, yeah I suppose that would work too!   Interesting there are a few different ways to achieve the same desired results here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer won't satisfy you but it's like that.

The clicking happens when the audio signal drops too strong. Perhaps you have a logical error in your LFO => When the LFO drops below 0 it starts clicking. That is pretty normal behaviour. See at my website gtube.de and select in the Database "dubstep like 2" and you can hear the clicking as well if you then reduce the amount from "GAIN 2" which acts as amplifier to 1999 you don't cross the 0 border of the filter and it won't click.

=> if you want to hear examples midi is not working correct at the moment.

Comment: thanks.  I updated my answer to be more precise.  Do you know how to control the LFO so that it doesn't go below zero, or above the current frequency value while an envelope is being applied ?

Answer (score 0):

If I change my codepen example code from :

`lfoGain.connect(filter.frequency);`

to :

`lfoGain.connect(filter.detune);`

The audible clicking is gone, and the synth sounds as I intend it to.

If anyone can explain why this works that would be helpful and I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If I change to

```
lfoGain.connect(filter.detune);
```

the sound itself is gone for me. I couldn't reproduce it.

If you want to make the clicking away i reduce the gain amount to

```
 lfoGain.gain.value = 2000;
```

Then it doesn't click and you have this nice "wable" effect.

Or do you just not want this wable effect?

You can as well  reduce the amount of time the wable takes to:

```
lfo.frequency.value = 1;
```

so it doesn't click. The clicking happens if the sound drops too fast. If the curve drops too fast than it clicks. Everywhere on every synthesizer always! And that's the right answer :)

Comment: After you edit the code to be `lfoGain.connect(filter.detune)`  Click on the rendered page where it says `Mouse Down here to start the filter envelope`.  When you mouse down you'll hear the filter start, and the LFO won't go above the filter's current frequency -- this is my desired behavior.